# Horizontal scroll by buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I want horizontal scrolling by buttons instead of scroll bar in my website.

For Example: http://www.entrepreneur.com/video/index.html

Here are thumbnails for videos are scrolling when left/right button at top right corner are pressed.

Comment: is this what you want to do http://erenyener.com/myLib/lib.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understanding your question correctly, You'd like to scroll a block element horizontally when a button is clicked.

EDIT: I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6pV/1/) for you to take a look at

```
 $("#fixedSize").animate({
            scrollLeft: $("#scrollAmount").val()
        })
```

That block is what creates the scrolling effect you're looking for.

Take a look at the jquery [scrollLeft](https://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/).

Let me know if this helps!